# programmatically trigger a button click

Tags: java, android

I got a problem on my android studio app. i want to programmatically trigger a click on a button when it go in the if else statement but it doesn't work. Can u guyz help me. Newbei here! Heres my code..

```
enemy_left.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if (motionEvent.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                run(1);
            }else if (motionEvent.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                standby(1);
            }
            enemy.setScaleX(-1f);
            float x=enemy.getX();
            float n= (float) 5.00;
            float v = x - n;
            enemy.setX(v);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

here is my if else statement where i want to performClick.. but does not work

```
if(bida1<kontra1){
      enemy_left.performClick(); //does not work the perform click here... :(
  }
```

Comment: Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A click on Button means execution of set of instructions.
I would suggest you to write the button.onClick instructions in a method like:

```
void codeToBeImplemented(){
      //Your Logic
}
```

and then calling this method on button click or programmatically when needed.

> Calling the method on Button click:

```
enemy_left.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                codeToBeImplemented();
            }
        });
```

> Calling the method programmatically anywhere, In your case in

```
if(bida1<kontra1){
    codeToBeImplemented();
}
```